# Can't find the texture folder with particles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

Im trying to change the water dripping, lava dripping and spore blossom particles but i can't find it at all. The only thing i found was the .json file where it leads to the "drip_fall.png" texture but its completely white for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What Version?

For me 1.13.2 is located at `minecraft\textures\particle\particles.png`
Maybe newer version may have a different file structure

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at 1.16.5 files, and there are two textures, one for when it's hanging on the ceiling when it drips, and one where it's falling. They are mostly white because the color is hardcoded. What this means is that you can change the shape of the particles however you like, but the color will always be the same. This applies to both lava and water particles, but I'm not so sure about spore blossoms. So, just change the image to whatever shape you want and then leave it white and the game will code the colors for you (I think).